# How to get the complete path of source C file from its corresponsing binary object file using shell script

Tags: shell, gcc, scripting, binaryfiles

I have object file uart.o I am trying to get the complete path of the source file from binary file. I am using GCC RENESAS and COSMIC compilers. 
I am using command - strings -a -f uart.o | grep "uart.c" to get the lines containing paths from the string command. I get random data along with the lines. Can I get complete path of a source file from an object file in any other way by shell?

Answer (score 4):

If your object/library/binary files have been built with debugging symbols (`-g` option to `gcc`), then this information will be contained in the debugging information.  You can use the gdb `info sources` command to get this list.

As a shell one-liner:

```
$ gdb -q -ex "set height 0" -ex "info sources" -ex quit my_obj_file.o
Reading symbols from my_obj_file.o...done.
Source files for which symbols have been read in:

/home/ubuntu/my_c_file.c

Source files for which symbols will be read in on demand:


$
```

This object file was previously built as follows:

```
$ gcc -g -c my_c_file.c -o my_obj_file.o
$
```

The output list may be comma- and newline-separated, so you may need some `sed` or `awk` post-processing to transform this into a pure one-entry-per-line list.  Piping the output to `sed 's/ \+$//;s/, /\n/g;s/,$//'` is useful for putting each source file on its own line, without commas.

Answer (score 1):

An object file does not typically encode the full path to the corresponding source file.  Doing so would have security implications, since it would expose details of your local filesystem layout to anyone with access to the binary.

The compiler itself often is operating exclusively on relative paths, anyway, and doesn't know or care about the complete filesystem path.

Comment: I have compiler which encodes full paths for the files. Full or relative I need to extract these paths in some manner. How do I do this?

Comment: Maybe you could update your question to include details about which compiler you are using? That might help us come up with a more accurate answer.

Comment: GCC RENESAS COSMIC compilers

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal, but if you compile with debug switches you can get path from running objdump -s -j.debug_info

The Path will be in the output.